# Rss reader for android using corona sdk

Tags: rss, coronasdk

I get sample code from net for Rss Reader parsing.but it work fine in iphone but android

```
network.canDetectNetworkStatusChanges
```

this one is not working.please help me to fix this.i want rss parser for android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing where you got the code and without seeing it, you probably could take out the network.canDetectNetworkStatusChanges bit and do some other method of testing to see if you have network access.

It's likely that you have a module that I wrote, but its kind of old.  We published a blog post this week on Business apps and made a business sample app available that has a couple of RSS feeds in it.  It has the latest version of my RSS module in it.  I don't see where I'm using the network.canDetectNetworkStatusChange anywhere.

http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2013/10/09/a-look-inside-a-sample-corona-powered-business-app/